# How do I drag the entire Listview? (All the elements should be dragged when dragging one element.)

Tags: listview, qml

I have a listview of PDFimages in QML that needs to be dragged because they don't fit the screen. I can fit the pdf to my screen but then the text selection won't work correctly because the pagePointSize of the document is bigger than the height and width of the listview.
Basically, I need to drag the listview on its x axis so that I can drag and reveal the rest of the pdf document. Is this possible? Please give me a sample code for it.

I have tried dragging the delegate of the listview but only drags that particular item not the rest. If I could drag the rest of the items along with the item I'm dragging, that is also fine.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you can use a `ListView` inside a `Flickable` and set the `flickableDirection` to `HorizontalFlick`.

Comment: @SMR Let me try that.